# How to show metamod module only on k2 article view

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

How to show metamod module only on k2 article view and not category view ?

please help

Answer (score 0):

See this note about **loadmodule** feature in Joomla/K2 Articles if you need the module only for some articles:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article

If you need it for all K2 articles you may need to load conditionally a specific position from your template in this way:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'your_mod_position' ) && $option=='com_k2' && $view=='item') : ?>
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="your_mod_position" />
<?php endif; ?>
```